# How do I set the TEditMask format to both automatically insert spaces and use the spaces in pasted text?

Tags: delphi

Given this text for the **EditMask** property of a **TMaskEdit** control,

`>AAAAA_AAAAA_AAAAA_AAAAA_AAAAA_AAAAA_A;0;_`

When the user types, a space is automatically inserted after every 5 characters.

However, if the user pastes in text that already contains the spaces (for example, copied from an email we sent them), then each space uses up one of the required characters and the last 5 characters of the text are lost.

Is there a way to identify a particular character in the **TEditMask** so it is either empty or the specific character (in this case, a space)? Or is there a different control I could use?

Comment: Once you **don't** type a space and once you **do** enter spaces (through clipboard pasting) - yet you want the same outcome?

Comment: May be the best way is to do it is to use a classic TEdit and manage the mask by code in the OnChange event.

Comment: @AmigoJack. Yes. When a user pastes in text containing spaces, it matches those to the spaces required for the mask, but as the user types it puts the space in automatically. If the user types a space, it is ignored or perhaps moves the cursor to the next text block. I've seen it done for credit card numbers and IP addresses, where the - and . are put in even if the user doesn't type them, but if they do type them it is used for the - or . I might just use a variation of sub-classing the edit class and listening for the WM_PASTE message, to clear out the spaces from the pasted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `TMaskEdit` and its horrible optics and limitations. Since the text you want to operate on is rather short you can use a `TEdit` directly and react upon changes to its text:

- Always make the text uppercase.
- Don't rely on keyboard versus mouse input.
- Kill all spaces on purpose and put them anywhere you want for optic reasons.

Also don't make the mistake to use several `TEdit`s for each block of text, as that will disrupt anyone who wants to paste the clipboard content of the long serial(?) at once - I've seen software installations doing this and it was always a pain.

Have an empty form, add a `TEdit` and make this its `OnChange` event:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change( Sender: TObject );
var
  edt: TEdit;  // Easier access
  sText: String;  // Easier access
  iLen, iPos, iCur: Integer;  // Text length, Character to inspect, Text cursor position
begin
  // Sender might be nil in rare conditions
  if not (Sender is TEdit) then exit;
  edt:= Sender as TEdit;

  // Empty texts don't need our care
  iLen:= Length( edt.Text );
  if iLen= 0 then exit;

  // I guess you always want big letters
  sText:= UpperCase( edt.Text );

  // Kill all spaces, so it doesn't matter how many are in there
  iCur:= edt.SelStart;  // Remember text cursor position
  iPos:= Pos( ' ', sText );  // Find first occurance
  while iPos> 0 do begin
    Delete( sText, iPos, 1 );
    Dec( iLen );
    if iCur>= iPos then Dec( iCur );  // Was text cursor after that spot? Should move, too.
    iPos:= Pos( ' ', sText );  // Find next occurance
  end;

  iPos:= 5;  // Character of the text to inspect
  while iPos< iLen do begin  // Much better than "<=", credit: Tom Brunberg
    if sText[iPos+ 1]<> ' ' then begin  // Next character is not a space?
      Insert( ' ', sText, iPos+ 1 );  // Insert space
      if iCur> iPos then Inc( iCur );  // Was text cursor after that spot? Should move, too.
      Inc( iLen );  // Text size has been increased by us
    end;

    Inc( iPos, 6 );  // Go to next end of a "block"
  end;

  edt.OnChange:= nil;  // Otherwise setting .Text will trigger this event again
  edt.Text:= sText;  // We're done
  edt.OnChange:= Edit1Change;
  edt.SelStart:= iCur;  // Recover/fix text cursor
end;
```

Successfully tested on D7:

[image: TEdit with fixed spaces in text]

Deleting only single characters feels weird, tho, <del>and does not work when the last one is a space</del>. I'll leave it to you to make it perfect.

Comment: IFIMA YSUGG EST,I N`WHI LEIPO S<=IL ENDOB EGIN` REMOV E'='

Comment: GREAT PATCH THANK SALOT 

Comment: In the block `if iPos= iLen then ...` you can also remove the  first part (as `iPos = iLen` will never be true), and only retain the `if sText[iPos+ 1]<> ' ' then begin ...` block.

Comment: @AmigoJack Your point about a text edit for each block of text was spot on. That's what it's doing at the moment and it's a real pain not being able to paste in the complete code. I had hoped a TMaskEdit would of handled it for me so I wouldn't need to write something like you've suggested. Maybe a TcxMaskEdit with a regular expression mask might but your answer is just easier for me to implement.